# Image sequence to binary classification with CNN and Transfomers

Tags: deep-learning, architecture, conv-neural-network, sequence, transformer-model

I'm trying to develop a model that can predict positive or negative given sequence of images. I'm planning to do that by first feed the sequence of images to CNN model and then to Transformer. Is this possible to do this? What kind of transformer should I use for this? If it possible please give information regarding architecture.

Thank you